# How to grab all numbers from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, integer

Let's say I have an input field and want to parse all of the numbers from the submitted string. For example, it could be:

```
Hi I'm 12 years old.
```

How do I parse all of the numbers without having a common pattern to work with?

I tried:

```
x.match(/\d+/)
```

but it only grabs the 12 and won't go past the next space, which is problematic if the user inputs more numbers with spaces in-between them.

Answer (score 12):

Add the `g` flag to return all matches in an array:

```
var matches = x.match(/\d+/g)
```

However, this may not catch numbers with seperators, like `1,000` or `0.123`

You may want to update your regex to:

```
x.match(/[0-9 , \.]+/g)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = sentence.split(" ");
var numbers = words.filter(function(w) {
    return w.match(/\d+/);
})
```